# Doctrine - PHP | How to Override EntityRepository existent methods?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I've created a superclass for my entities:

```
class superclass{
   /** @column(type="string", length=1,
    * options={"default":"c"})
   */
   protected $status;

  /** ...more things **/

}
```

The next step is create my own repository, so it replace EntityRepository. The aim is set the status value depending of:

- Entity is removed - 'd'
- Entity is modified - 'm'
- Entity is created - 'c'

So I need to override methods from EntityRepository: find(), findBy(), delete(),...

I didn't found any work related. Could it not be good idea?

Any clues? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes

Comment: @Cerad I've read it more times. It says: "When using a custom repository class, you still have access to the default finder methods such as find() and findAll()". I want override the defaults methods...

Comment: Make yourself a new repository by extending the default doctrine one and point your entity to it.  Then go wild.  If you want to change the behavior for multiple entities then make a base repository extending from the doctrine one then make a repository for each entity by extending your base repository.

Comment: Ok, I know very well how create my own entity repository which add new methods. But are there no extra problems if I override the default methods (find, findOneBy, etc..) ? This is the question of the post...

Does anyone codified something similar?

Comment: I do all the time.  The existing find() throws an error on null.  I override it and just return null for $id === null.  It's difficult to understand what you are actually asking.  As far as the status field, I think you want doctrine life cycle listeners.  But again it's unclear how that relates to find.

Comment: Could you show me code? This happend when I override the find method:

Fatal error: Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL in ....

The method signature is retrieved from http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own filters for the Doctrine's operations:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html

Answer (score 0):

Exists a project with similar dataflow. https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/softdeleteable.md

With simple annotations it creates and manages the deleted fields and extract the not deleted fields using the defaults EntityManager methods.